# AuthResult.credential = null when using login with Android Firebase Custom Token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase login with anonymous user for initial authentication to the app. Then when the user wants to signup permanently to the app I am using custom token authentication and linking the previous anonymous user auth with the custom token auth. Following is my code:

```
val auth = Firebase.auth
auth.currentUser?.let { currentAnonymousUser ->
    Log.d("CURRENT ANONYMOUS USER ID ${currentAnonymousUser.uid}")
    auth.signInWithCustomToken(customToken).addOnSuccessListener {
        try {
            val customTokenLoginCredential = it.credential
            Log.d("USER LOGIN WITH CUSTOM TOKEN SUCCESS")
            currentAnonymousUser.linkWithCredential(customTokenLoginCredential)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    Log.d("ANONYMOUS USER CONVERSION RESULT ${task.isSuccessful}")
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        // redirect user to registration
                    }
                }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            showLog("CREDENTIAL CATCH EXCEPTION ${ex.localizedMessage}")
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        showLog("USER LOGIN WITH CUSTOM TOKEN FAILURE")
    }
```

So, this problem has got me spiraling. I have followed the documentation for logging in with [firebase using custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth?hl=en&authuser=0) and the login is successful but the line **`it.credential` is returning null**, due to which the my login flow is getting broken.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here or if I can use another way to get the credential after custom token login success?

Comment: any udates on this?

Comment: @nzackoya not yet